# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Only splitting my query works to fix this

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good afternoon everyone,

Towards the end of my query I start sending PVP Mail Rewards to my players for the game I'm hosting. The issue is that all the queries work successfully until the very last one.

I think this error is generated after the functions I am calling are returning a value causing the script to go bonkers at the end. I can resolve this by splitting all my PVP Mail rewards in to different queries, but I would really prefer keeping them in one master query with all the other things I'm sending.

How would I go about fixing this? Thanks for your time and patience to read this.

Here is the error

```
> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Server LAPTOP-K2EKS8H0, Procedure , Line 0
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
> [21000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. (512)

> Time: 0.029s
```

```
-- Create temporary table to hold data from dbo.Characters and dbo.PVPRanking --

USE DNWorld

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempAccountTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #TempAccountTable
end

Select AccountID, G.AccountName, G.CharacterName, PVPLevel, PVPExp, TotalRank
INTO #TempAccountTable
FROM Characters as G
INNER JOIN (
         SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalRank) AS rn
         FROM PvPRanking
        Where totalrank between 1 and 100
     ) as tmp on tmp.CharacterID = G.CharacterID
;




--------------------------------------------------- Rank 1 PvP QC Distribution ---------------------------------------------------

USE DNMembership
GO
DECLARE @AccountName nvarchar(50), @CompensationAmt INT, @i int = 0, @Rank1Rewards int

SET @Rank1Rewards = 1

-- Set and deliver QC by their total rank.
SET @AccountName = (SELECT AccountName FROM #TempAccountTable where TotalRank = 1)
EXEC dbo.P_AddCashIncome @AccountName, 2, NULL, NULL, @Rank1Rewards
;


--------------------------------------------------- PVP Rank #2 - #10 QC distribution via while loop ---------------------------------------------------
USE DNMembership
GO
DECLARE @AccountName nvarchar(50), @CompensationAmt INT, @i int = 0, @RankRewards int

SET @RankRewards = 2

WHILE (@i <= 10) -- BE AWARE IF EDITING
BEGIN
SET @i = @i + 1


SET @AccountName = (SELECT AccountName FROM #TempAccountTable where TotalRank = 1 + @i) -- BE AWARE IF EDITING
EXEC dbo.P_AddCashIncome @AccountName, 2, NULL, NULL, @RankRewards;
END;

-- PVP Rank #11 - #25 distribution via while loop
USE DNMembership
GO
DECLARE @AccountName nvarchar(50), @CompensationAmt INT, @i int = 0, @RankRewards int

SET @RankRewards = 3

WHILE (@i <= 25)
BEGIN
SET @i = @i + 1


SET @AccountName = (SELECT AccountName FROM #TempAccountTable where TotalRank = 10 + @i)
EXEC dbo.P_AddCashIncome @AccountName, 2, NULL, NULL, @RankRewards;
END;

--------------------------------------------------- PVP Rank #26 - #100 QC distribution via while loop ---------------------------------------------------
USE DNMembership
GO
DECLARE @AccountName nvarchar(50), @CompensationAmt INT, @i int = 0, @RankRewards int

SET @RankRewards = 4

WHILE (@i <= 100)
BEGIN
SET @i = @i + 1


SET @AccountName = (SELECT AccountName FROM #TempAccountTable where TotalRank = 25 + @i)
EXEC dbo.P_AddCashIncome @AccountName, 2, NULL, NULL, @RankRewards;
END;



--------------------------------------------------- PVP Mail Rewards #2 - #10 ---------------------------------------------------

USE DNWorld
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


DECLARE
    @nvcSenderName nvarchar(50),
    @Subject       nvarchar(50),
    @Content       nvarchar(300),
    @CharacterName nvarchar(50),
    @CoinAmount     bigint,
    @ItemID1       bigint ,
    @ItemID2       bigint ,
    @insItemCount1 smallint,
    @insItemCount2 smallint,
    @LevelItem1    bigint,
    @LevelItem2    bigint,
    @MailTabCode tinyint,
    @i int = 0

WHILE (@i <= 10) -- BE AWARE IF EDITING
BEGIN
SET @i = @i + 1

-- FROM
SET @nvcSenderName = 'PVP Logistics Bot'
-- SUBJECT
SET @Subject = 'Top 10 Player Killers'
-- MESSAGE
SET @Content = 'Outstanding job on maintaining your status as one of the top 10 players throughout Skitzovania.'
-- TARGET CHAR and Loop to desired rank #
SET @CharacterName = (SELECT CharacterName FROM #TempAccountTable where TotalRank = 1 + @i)
-- COPPER
SET @CoinAmount = '0'
-- ITEM ID
SET @ItemID1 = '374341682' -- Goddess Medal
SET @ItemID2 = '335833344' -- Warrior's Trophy
-- QUANTITY
SET @insItemCount1 = '1'
SET @insItemCount2 = '2'
-- ENHANCEMENT LEVEL
SET @LevelItem1 = '0'
SET @LevelItem2 = '0'
-- MAIL TAB TYPE
-- 0 All, 1 Character, 2 Contents, 3 Event, 4 System
SET @MailTabCode = 4

DECLARE
    @ItemSerial1 bigint
DECLARE
    @ItemSerialfix1 bigint
DECLARE
    @inbReceiverCharacterID int

BEGIN
    SET @inbReceiverCharacterID = (Select CharacterID from DNWorld.dbo.Characters where CharacterName = @CharacterName)
    SET @ItemSerial1 = (SELECT max(ItemSerial) as ItemSerial
                        FROM dnworld.dbo.MaterializedItems)
    SET @ItemSerialfix1 = (@ItemSerial1 + 1)

    DECLARE
    @ItemSerial2 bigint
DECLARE
    @ItemSerialfix2 bigint

    SET @ItemSerial2 = (SELECT max(ItemSerial) as ItemSerial
                        FROM dnworld.dbo.MaterializedItems)
    SET @ItemSerialfix2 = (@ItemSerial2 + 1)

    EXEC DNWorld.dbo.P_SendSystemMail
         @nvcSenderName,
         @inbReceiverCharacterID,
         3,
         4,
         @Subject,
         @Content,
         @CoinAmount,
         @ItemSerialfix1,
         @ItemID1,
         @insItemCount1,
         24000,
         0,
         @LevelItem1,
         0,
         0,
         1,
         0,
         1,
         0,
         @ItemSerialfix2,
         @itemid2,
         @intChannelID = 0,
         @intMapID = 0,
         @intTotalMailCount = null,
         @intNotReadMailCount = 1,
         @int7DaysLeftMailCount = null,
         @intMailID = null,
         @inyMailTabCode = @MailTabCode
END
    END
GO


--------------------------------------------------- PVP Mail Rewards #11 - #25 ---------------------------------------------------

USE DNWorld
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


DECLARE
    @nvcSenderName nvarchar(50),
    @Subject       nvarchar(50),
    @Content       nvarchar(300),
    @CharacterName nvarchar(50),
    @CoinAmount     bigint,
    @ItemID1       bigint ,
    @ItemID2       bigint ,
    @insItemCount1 smallint,
    @insItemCount2 smallint,
    @LevelItem1    bigint,
    @LevelItem2    bigint,
    @MailTabCode tinyint,
    @i int = 0

WHILE (@i <= 25) -- BE AWARE IF EDITING
BEGIN
SET @i = @i + 1

-- FROM
SET @nvcSenderName = 'PVP Logistics Bot'
-- SUBJECT
SET @Subject = 'Top 25 Player Killers'
-- MESSAGE
SET @Content = 'Outstanding job on maintaining your status as one of the top 25 players throughout Skitzovania.'
-- TARGET CHAR and Loop to desired rank #
SET @CharacterName = (SELECT CharacterName FROM #TempAccountTable where TotalRank = 10 + @i)
-- COPPER
SET @CoinAmount = '0'
-- ITEM ID
SET @ItemID1 = '374341682' -- Goddess Medal
SET @ItemID2 = '335833344' -- Warrior's Trophy
-- QUANTITY
SET @insItemCount1 = '1'
SET @insItemCount2 = '2'
-- ENHANCEMENT LEVEL
SET @LevelItem1 = '0'
SET @LevelItem2 = '0'
-- MAIL TAB TYPE
-- 0 All, 1 Character, 2 Contents, 3 Event, 4 System
SET @MailTabCode = 4

DECLARE
    @ItemSerial1 bigint
DECLARE
    @ItemSerialfix1 bigint
DECLARE
    @inbReceiverCharacterID int

BEGIN
    SET @inbReceiverCharacterID = (Select CharacterID from DNWorld.dbo.Characters where CharacterName = @CharacterName)
    SET @ItemSerial1 = (SELECT max(ItemSerial) as ItemSerial
                        FROM dnworld.dbo.MaterializedItems)
    SET @ItemSerialfix1 = (@ItemSerial1 + 1)

    DECLARE
    @ItemSerial2 bigint
DECLARE
    @ItemSerialfix2 bigint

    SET @ItemSerial2 = (SELECT max(ItemSerial) as ItemSerial
                        FROM dnworld.dbo.MaterializedItems)
    SET @ItemSerialfix2 = (@ItemSerial2 + 1)

    EXEC DNWorld.dbo.P_SendSystemMail
         @nvcSenderName,
         @inbReceiverCharacterID,
         3,
         4,
         @Subject,
         @Content,
         @CoinAmount,
         @ItemSerialfix1,
         @ItemID1,
         @insItemCount1,
         24000,
         0,
         @LevelItem1,
         0,
         0,
         1,
         0,
         1,
         0,
         @ItemSerialfix2,
         @itemid2,
         @intChannelID = 0,
         @intMapID = 0,
         @intTotalMailCount = null,
         @intNotReadMailCount = 1,
         @int7DaysLeftMailCount = null,
         @intMailID = null,
         @inyMailTabCode = @MailTabCode
END
    END
GO


--------------------------------------------------- PVP Mail Rewards #26 - #100 ---------------------------------------------------

USE DNWorld
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


DECLARE
    @nvcSenderName nvarchar(50),
    @Subject       nvarchar(50),
    @Content       nvarchar(300),
    @CharacterName nvarchar(50),
    @CoinAmount     bigint,
    @ItemID1       bigint ,
    @ItemID2       bigint ,
    @insItemCount1 smallint,
    @insItemCount2 smallint,
    @LevelItem1    bigint,
    @LevelItem2    bigint,
    @MailTabCode tinyint,
    @i int = 0

WHILE (@i <= 100) -- BE AWARE IF EDITING
BEGIN
SET @i = @i + 1

-- FROM
SET @nvcSenderName = 'PVP Logistics Bot'
-- SUBJECT
SET @Subject = 'Top 100 Player Killers'
-- MESSAGE
SET @Content = 'Outstanding job on maintaining your status as one of the top 100 players throughout Skitzovania.'
-- TARGET CHAR and Loop to desired rank #
SET @CharacterName = (SELECT CharacterName FROM #TempAccountTable where TotalRank = 25 + @i)
-- COPPER
SET @CoinAmount = '0'
-- ITEM ID
SET @ItemID1 = '374341682' -- Goddess Medal
SET @ItemID2 = '335833344' -- Warrior's Trophy
-- QUANTITY
SET @insItemCount1 = '1'
SET @insItemCount2 = '2'
-- ENHANCEMENT LEVEL
SET @LevelItem1 = '0'
SET @LevelItem2 = '0'
-- MAIL TAB TYPE
-- 0 All, 1 Character, 2 Contents, 3 Event, 4 System
SET @MailTabCode = 4

DECLARE
    @ItemSerial1 bigint
DECLARE
    @ItemSerialfix1 bigint
DECLARE
    @inbReceiverCharacterID int

BEGIN
    SET @inbReceiverCharacterID = (Select CharacterID from DNWorld.dbo.Characters where CharacterName = @CharacterName)
    SET @ItemSerial1 = (SELECT max(ItemSerial) as ItemSerial
                        FROM dnworld.dbo.MaterializedItems)
    SET @ItemSerialfix1 = (@ItemSerial1 + 1)

    DECLARE
    @ItemSerial2 bigint
DECLARE
    @ItemSerialfix2 bigint

    SET @ItemSerial2 = (SELECT max(ItemSerial) as ItemSerial
                        FROM dnworld.dbo.MaterializedItems)
    SET @ItemSerialfix2 = (@ItemSerial2 + 1)

    EXEC DNWorld.dbo.P_SendSystemMail
         @nvcSenderName,
         @inbReceiverCharacterID,
         3,
         4,
         @Subject,
         @Content,
         @CoinAmount,
         @ItemSerialfix1,
         @ItemID1,
         @insItemCount1,
         24000,
         0,
         @LevelItem1,
         0,
         0,
         1,
         0,
         1,
         0,
         @ItemSerialfix2,
         @itemid2,
         @intChannelID = 0,
         @intMapID = 0,
         @intTotalMailCount = null,
         @intNotReadMailCount = 1,
         @int7DaysLeftMailCount = null,
         @intMailID = null,
         @inyMailTabCode = @MailTabCode
END
    END
GO
```

Comment: Sample data/sample results would be helpful to better understand the problem :)  Please consider posting a SQL Fiddle, for example: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Presumably there is more than one row which has `TotalRank = 1`

Comment: What is the data type of first parameter of `P_AddCashIncome`? Can you make changes to that stored procedure? if your query returns multiple values from `SELECT AccountName FROM #TempAccountTable where TotalRank = 1`, which one to take.

Just execute the query `SELECT AccountName FROM #TempAccountTable where TotalRank = 1` and you would get multiple account numbers and you should know that a varable of nvarchar cannot hold multiple values

Comment: You probably have more than 100 rows in PvPRanking where `TotalRank between 1 and 100` causing multiple rows to be returned in your `set @Variable = (select...)` statements, i.e.: duplicate TotalRank values. Also `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalRank) AS rn` is redundant as it's not used anywhere.